# How to load files based on if they exist, and then iteratively add them to a Spark dataframe so that non-existent files are skipped?

Tags: apache-spark, for-loop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am conditionally loading in files and was wondering what is the best way to do the following:

1. If the file exists, read it in.
2. Iteratively do this such that each existing file gets added to a Spark dataframe.
3. Result will be one large Spark dataframe containing all existing files from the list of paths provide.

This is what I have but it does not work correctly.

```
for path in list_of_paths:
    if s3.exists(path):
        sdf = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(path)
final_sdf = sdf.union(sdf)
```

The added challenge is that these files change very rapidly, such that if I perform an initial check of file existence, by the time I load them, they may no longer technically exist.

Thus the order of operations needs to be to check the file's existence and load it immediately if it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the dataframes into a list, and use `reduce` and `unionAll` to combine them into a single dataframe:

```
from functools import reduce

sdf_list = [spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(path) for path in list_of_paths if s3.exists(path)]
final_sdf = reduce(lambda a, b: a.unionAll(b), sdf_list)
```

Or you can filter the list and provide the whole list to the Spark reader, which should be more efficient:

```
paths = [path for path in list_of_paths if s3.exists(path)]
final_sdf = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(paths)
```

Comment: AH thank you. The second one works perfectly. I am curious though...the first one errored out -  `Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types.`

Comment: that might mean your dataframes have different column types...

Comment: but if you use the second method, spark will merge the column types for you

Comment: whoa very delayed on this, but is there a way to do this using a try except loop? (I can update the question, and if this is against the rules I can post a different one as well, because so far this has been extremely helpful) the issue with these files is they change very rapidly and there are many of them, so by the time the list comprehension is done and we have begun loading, those files could no longer be valid.

Comment: Spark uses lazy evaluation, so even if you use a try/except it wouldn't help because Spark isn't going to read your file right away. Maybe you'll need some in-memory frameworks like pandas

Comment: thank you for your comment. unfortunately this is a very large amount of data so I don't think I will be able to bring it to pandas.

Comment: If you have a large amount of data, which rapidly disappears, I suppose you should find a way to store them somewhere on disk, because Spark can't just put everything in memory.